# How to get the birthdate as a todays date

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to get the birthdate as a todays date

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO time_line(tl_dob, tl_name, tl_message)
VALUES(new.em_DOB, new.em_first_name, 'Happy Birth Day');

INSERT INTO time_line(tl_dob, tl_name, tl_message)
VALUES(new.em_DOJ, new.em_first_name, 'Congrats');

END
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: try using getdate()

Comment: here, I am getting the date of birth like example 1993/10/12 I want after inserting data and after fetching back I should get as  2017/10/12

Comment: dude make the question clear

Comment: here, I am triggering a table

Comment: this is for birthday notification

Comment: then take only the day and month not the year

Comment: is there any possibility to convert year

Comment: which database are u using ?

Comment: take day(dob) and month(dob)

Comment: MySQL data base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one...

```
concat(year(curdate()),'-',month(dob),'-',day(dob))
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * from time_line where MONTH(tl_dob) = MONTH (NOW()) AND DAY(tl_dob) = DAY(NOW())";

Comment: this is my PHP query

Comment: whats the problem now ?

Comment: where to this code     concat(year(curdate()),'-',month(dob),'-',day(dob))

Comment: actually the code you did is right what is the error

Comment: I am getting YEAR Too.

Comment: sorry i don't get u

Comment: From PHP code I am Getting Year also for displaying notification

Comment: $sql = "SELECT *,CURDATE() from time_line where MONTH(tl_dob) = MONTH (NOW()) AND DAY(tl_dob) = DAY(NOW())"; use this then

Comment: Hi, I will Clear You Now. First, the above code is a trigger for showing notification. Next first insertion is for showing notification next I want to show the date of joining message as 1 year completed, 2 years completed, can you tell me something like this. here I want to validate date of joining and display message on that basis.

Comment: select concat(cast(year(curdate())-year(dt) as char(50)),' year completed') from time_line where MONTH(dt) = MONTH (NOW()) AND DAY(dt)= DAY(NOW()                          will this be helpful